# Eleven students into two groups of four and one of three

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The problem: 11 students are to be divided into 3 groups, 2 groups of 4 students and 1 group of 3 students. In how many ways can I do this?

The order of the groups and the order of the students in every group doesn't matter

I just followed the formula and got

$ 11!\choose  4! (11-4)!$*
$ 7!\choose  4! (7-4)!$*
$3!\choose 3!(3-3)!$

and thought i solved it. So our teacher did it in class afterwards and he decided it should be

$11\choose 4$ *
 $7\choose 4$ *
 $3\choose 3$ /2

my question is why is it /2 at the end? is it because there are 2 groups that are equal?

Could someone show me the correct way to do it? So I got it clarified.

Thanks

Comment: What do the two answers work out to numerically?

Comment: @bof If the two size-4 groups are distinct, the given answer is correct. If they are not distinct, the answer must be halved.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I know that. You should explain it to Huskey.

Comment: @Huskey, in one of your edits, you changed what started as *fractions* into what now look like binomial coefficients, e.g., $11!\over4!(11-4)!$ into $11!\choose4!(11-4)!$.  (You also used an awfully complicated way of reformatting what "\choose" does easily.)

Comment: @Barry Cipra, i tried { y \choose x} actually but nothing happened.... :(

Comment: @Huskey, you need to put dollar signs around math expressions.  Give it a try.

Comment: ahh didn't know that, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have been mentioned in the question that the groups are *unlabelled*, i.e. indistinguishable, except by size.

The reason may be clearer if we consider one such division
We would consider $ABCD\;|\; EFGH | IJK $, and, say $EFGH\; |IJK\;|ABCD $ **to be identical divisions.**

Using permutations, we would write the answer as $\;\dfrac{11!}{(4!4!3!)\times(2!)}$

The denominator's first part removes permutations **within** groups,
and the $2!$ removes those **between** indistinguishable groups

It could, of course, instead be written as the book has done, viz. $\binom{11}4\binom7{4}\binom33 /2$

Comment: Oh this was the answer I was looking for. I just copied the question from the exam. So I understand why it was hard for you to understand it as well. The teacher should probably mention that the groups are indistinguishable.

Great explanation though! :)

Comment: Glad you liked the explanation ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get the answer:  Line the $11$ students up from left to right.  Pick $3$ of them for the group of three, which can be done in $11\choose3$ ways.  Of the remaining students, the leftmost one must go into a group with $3$ of the other $7$, who can be chosen in $7\choose3$ ways.  So the total number of ways the groups can be formed is

$${11\choose3}{7\choose3}$$

Comment: Nice variation ! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

The answer calls for the use of *multinomial coefficients*. See e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialCoefficient.html for more.

If we have a set of $n$ elements to be partitioned into $k$ subsets with $n_1, \ldots, n_k$ elements, respectively (where $\sum^m_{i=1} n_i = n$), then there are

$$ \binom{n}{n_1, \ldots, n_k} = \frac{n!}{n_1! \cdots n_k!} $$

ways to do this. The number $\binom{n}{n_1, \ldots, n_k}$ is called a multinomial coefficient.

Comment: The multinomial coefficient counts *labeled* groups of size $n_1,\ldots,n_k$.  It's what the OP got and thought was right.

Comment: OK. This was not clear from the question (at least not to me), but I see that now.

Comment: Ah, I just took a look at the question's edit history; things were initially unclear.

Comment: Yeah~ sorry for that, didnt know there was a "preview" section before you submit a post.